# Nagios - check if a process is listening to a port

Tags: tcp, port, monitoring, nagios

Is there any command which checks that a certain process is listening to a port.
I have tried check_tcp but it does not output which process is listening to a port
Its output was:

`TCP OK - 0.000 second response time on port 8443|time=0.000421s;;;0.000000;10.000000`

Comment: Wouldn't it be inferred from the port number that you're checking which process is listening on it?

Comment: I want to assert that port is being listened by my expected process

Comment: Checking that the process on your port is actually responding to requests is a better check.  In your example you're checking port 8443 so it's assumed to be `https`.  Seems `check_http` would be the right choice in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anything on the Nagios Plugins Exchange to meet your needs, so I wrote one to be used with [NRPE](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Monitoring-Agents/NRPE--2D-Nagios-Remote-Plugin-Executor/details).

https://github.com/jlyoung/nagios_check_listening_port_linux

Output looks like this:

```
[root@joeyoung.io ~]# python /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/nagios_check_listening_port_linux.py -n nginx -p 80
OK. nginx found listening on port 80 for the following address(es): [0.0.0.0] | 'listening_on_expected_port'=1;;;;

[root@joeyoung.io ~]# python /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/nagios_check_listening_port_linux.py -n nginx -p 9999
CRITICAL - No process named nginx could be found listening on port 9999 | 'listening_on_expected_port'=0;;;;
```